# Set UI Language Windows with SetLocaleInfo

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, winapi

I want to change the default language for windows system. From powershell, there is a way to do this using

`Set-WinUILanguageOverride -Language de-DE` (Changes language to German)

However, I am looking for a win32 api call for same. Tried `SetLocaleInfo` , but it wasn't working.The following code prints 0 as the SetLocaleInfo is failing. `GetLastError()` returned `ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS`, but not sure which flag needs to go here. Thanks.

```
int main()
{
    LCID lcid = GetSystemDefaultLCID();
    cout << "system default >> " << lcid << endl;

    wstring regionCode;
    
    //Tatar Russia
    lcid = 1092;
    regionCode = L"0x0444";
    cout << "Tatar Russia " << SetLocaleInfo(lcid, LOCALE_FONTSIGNATURE | LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME, regionCode.c_str()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-information-constants) indicates that both of the flags your are passing are valid for `GetLocaleInfo`, and not valid for `SetLocaleInfo`.

Comment: Any idea on what could be the valid flag(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Petesh said, The two `LCType` you used are invalid for the `SetLocaleInfo` function,and there is no valid flag for `SetLocaleInfo` that can set the UI language of windows system.

According to the [`User Interface Language Management`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/user-interface-language-management):

> **User UI Language**
>
> To retrieve the user UI language, an application can call [`GetUserDefaultUILanguage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultuilanguage) or [`GetUserPreferredUILanguages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserpreferreduilanguages). The application cannot change the user UI language, as there is no function to set it.

Therefore, there is no suitable Windows32 API that can modify the UI language of the windows system.